# Is there a way of automatically showing the corresponding part in compiled file when pointing at certain line of codes in console?

Tags: overleaf

Hi I'd like to use Latex to note down the mathmetic equations with some explanations. However, finding the corresponding codes of notes are time-consuming when there are too much contents in it.

Is there any package or setting to visually link the codes (left console) with its output (right pdf)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you looking for SyncTeX?

Comment: You tagged this Overleaf, there this functionality is available by default. On the border between the code view and the output view there are two arrows, one labelled "Go to code location in PDF" and the other "Go to PDF location in code", which do exactly what you want. Many offline editors also implement this, such as TeXstudio.