# How to avoid returning to the first page of PDF after compiling in Overleaf?

Tags: compiling, overleaf

I want to see the page corresponding to edited Tex page when I compile the file on Overleaf, but it always return to the first page in PDF file. How can I fix this?

Comment: Refer to the comment under question [overleaf - Is there a way of automatically showing the corresponding part in compiled file when pointing at certain line of codes in console? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566942/is-there-a-way-of-automatically-showing-the-corresponding-part-in-compiled-file)

Comment: Solved, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue via

[https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_to_jump_to_the_source_code_from_the_typeset_PDF_(SyncTeX)[][1]](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_to_jump_to_the_source_code_from_the_typeset_PDF_(SyncTeX)%5B%5D%5B1%5D)